# How to keep video and audio together in the Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I import video footage in the Video Sequence Editor, it separates into a video strip and an audio strip. Fine.

But it's also possible, even accidentally, to afterward move these strips separately from each other. I don't want that to happen. I can't even think of a reason why the voice of the person speaking in the video should ever be out of sync with the person talking.

So, how can I **block the video strip and audio strip of moving separately from one another**?

Comment: Its actually very useful and common to edit the two separately. Often editors will remove pauses, ums, uhhs, etc from a recording but don't want jump cuts in the video so they will cut up the audio and play b-roll or use a shot where the speakers face isn't seen. Its also important for timing as viewers tend to have very short attention spans these days. 

Dedicated programs Like Ardour for the audio are often better than VSE (With exceptions). I don't actually use VSE much but my suggestion would be to select your two tracks and try to parent them. Or check the tool/property panels .

Comment: One way would be to combine the sound and video into a "Meta-strip" (GTL-G)
The Meta-strip can be cut and moved about as you would a strip of movie film with sound locked to it. Remaining sections can be selected and restored as two again if necessary, i think with ALT-G.  (I'll have to go check)  To add smoother/softer transitions between sections or to fill in gaps you can copy and mix in some ambient sound from the same sound strip

Answer (score 4):

To keep video and audio in sync, use the parenting function in the VSEQF add-on:
https://github.com/snuq/VSEQF

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can select them both and group them into a meta strip (`CRTL+G` or right click and select "Make meta strip").

They become a single strip.

If you then want to edit stuff inside the meta strip, just select it and press Tab.